# Breeze OData - Insert and Update

Tags: odata, breeze

I have managed to get data via OData. Now I try to **update** and **insert** data via OData. But I cannot figure out how and I cannot find appropriate documentation. Could someone please provide some hints (URLs, etc.).

Thankx, Harry

Answer (score 1):

Simply call EntityManager.saveChanges(...).  Breeze will create an OData batch transaction and submit it to the server.

Comment: Thankx Jay. How does the Controller have to look like? I have something like:

public class XxxController : EntitySetController<Xxx, int>
{
   public override HttpResponseMessage Patch(int key, Delta<Xxx> patch)
   {
      //...
   }
}

Comment: Typically you will not go thru the Microsoft WebApi for an OData service. You would expose your service directly via WCF Data Services (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx ).  MS has an incomplete version of OData thru WebApi available now but it does not support $select, $expand or batch saves yet ( MS says that these features are scheduled for release later this year). So your best bet for now is to use WCF data services if you want go thru OData, or just use the Breeze Web Api stuff directly and skip having an OData endpoint. The Breeze Web Api provides the same capabilities

Comment: Thankx Jay! I found the following link where there is OData with WebApi doing CRUD operations: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-crud-operations. They are even doing Patch operations. Is this not yet availalbe in Breeze? Are there any plans of supporting this?

Comment: The problem with $patch is that it is not transactional.  We decided to wait until MS supports $batch operations with WebApi (They are part of the OData spec).  They claim that this will be part of their next release.  The current OData WebApi is pretty anemic, i.e. they have just skipped big portions of the spec. Just curious if there is any reason you cannot use WCF data services until then?

Comment: Thankx Jay. There are no specific reason abart from not having another technical way to get data. At the moment we would like to stick with Web API...

Comment: You can stick with WebApi, just don't use the WebApi OData bits. Use the Breeze WebApi impl directly.  This is what all of the Breeze samples do.